# Debian fails to boot on new kernel but runs fine under old kernel, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, nvidia, display

Following a bump from Bullseye to Bookworm, Debian is unable to boot under its newest kernel. The new kernel `6.1.0-11` does not work at all. After displaying the booting to kernel message, there is no output on the screen at all. My monitor displays a warning that says there is no input at all and goes to power-saver mode. I initially thought the upgrade fried the system but kernel `5.10.0-25` boots ok without the use of recovery mode.

Since there was no output I thought the [nvidia display driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/210649/en-us/) was incompatible. However `dkms` output seems to suggest that it might not be the reason:

```bash
$ sudo dkms status
nvidia/535.104.05, 5.10.0-25-amd64, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.104.05, 6.1.0-11-amd64, x86_64: installed
v4l2loopback/0.12.7, 5.10.0-25-amd64, x86_64: installed
v4l2loopback/0.12.7, 6.1.0-11-amd64, x86_64: installed
xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2, 5.10.0-25-amd64, x86_64: installed
xtrx/0.0.1+git20190320.5ae3a3e-3.2, 6.1.0-11-amd64, x86_64: installed
```

I thought of just keep using the old kernel while searching a solution, but every time I `apt upgrade` something whines about it expecting the new kernel and keeps asking me to restart sessions. How can I diagnose the cause when the system is not outputting anything to begin with? If I am unable to come up with a solution, how can I change GRUB settings so that `5.10.0-25` is the default and GRUB boots to it automatically?

Comment: Once booted into the old kernel, I would check the log files in `/var/log` (boot.log*, syslog.*, kern.log* etc) to see what is causing the issue

Comment: Disable nvidia driver. Just to be sure (you may need to disable other parts, just to find real cause. mark down all changes you did, to restore when you found the reason. DO NOT TRUST YOUR MEMORY. Write down exactly where and what you changed. Boot with `single` in GRUB. Note DKMS say it is installed, not that it work as expected.